# Clean Code: Is defining an abstract class without any abstract methods a Java Practice?

Tags: java, coding-style, abstract-class

Currently, I have this code to create a base class with methods for their children classes. But I haven't declared any `abstract` classes. Is it a Java practice?

Comment: Use abstract class when u have common methods which will be used in the sub classes and you never want anyone to create an object of the this class.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirement. If you intend to write the base class only for getting extended you can declare it abstract. An abstract class provides you a default behaviour otherwise you can also write an interface if you only need to declare methods.